# Non-existent class: CI_Curl

Tags: php, curl, codeigniter-3

I am trying to use this Curl Library from this site.
[Link to the Curl Library](https://www.formget.com/curl-library-codeigniter/)

They have clearly stated to put my Library file inside

```
 ci_demo > system > libraries > curl.php
```

I have done the same. When I try to load into my Controller it throws me this error: `Non-existent class: CI_Curl`. 
My code is :

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user_model');

    }

    public function getAllUsers(){

    $this->load->library('curl');

//  Setting URL To Fetch Data From
$this->curl->create('https://www.formget.com/');

//  To Temporarily Store Data Received From Server
$this->curl->option('buffersize', 10);

//  To support Different Browsers
$this->curl->option('useragent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)');

//  To Receive Data Returned From Server
$this->curl->option('returntransfer', 1);

//  To follow The URL Provided For Website
$this->curl->option('followlocation', 1);

//  To Retrieve Server Related Data
$this->curl->option('HEADER', true);

//  To Set Time For Process Timeout
$this->curl->option('connecttimeout', 600);

//  To Execute 'option' Array Into cURL Library & Store Returned Data Into $data
$data = $this->curl->execute();

//  To Display Returned Data
echo $data;
}
//and so on
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change class name of curl:

```
class Curl {
```

to

```
class CI_Curl {
```

Comment: The I guess I have to chaange the file name too ? right?

Comment: No no need to change filename. Change only class name.

Comment: in codeigniter v3 That is not required only the points to notei is First lettler is capital & Class name & file name must match. For More  https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html